# Merging unique values from two different columns into a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, unique-values

How do I merge the unique values in columns `A` and `B` from `df` into `list`?

```
id  A   B
1   x   k
2   y   x
3   x   l
4   x   k
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
list = ['x', 'y', 'k', 'l']
```

Failed attempt:

```
list = df['A'].unique().tolist()
list.append(df['B'].unique())
```

The output:

```
['x', 'y', ['x', 'k', 'l']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.ravel` and `np.unique`:

```
# Global unique
>>> np.unique(np.ravel(df[['A', 'B']])).tolist()
['k', 'l', 'x', 'y']

# Per column unique
>>> df['A'].unique().tolist() + df['B'].unique().tolist()
['x', 'y', 'k', 'x', 'l']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pandas.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) with [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) for unique values in original ordering:

```
L = pd.unique(np.ravel(df[['A','B']], order='F')).tolist()
```

Another solutions with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) or [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stabltransfe/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)

```
L = df[['A','B']].unstack().unique().tolist()
L = df[['A','B']].melt()['value'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
L = df[['A','B']].melt()['value'].unique().tolist()
L = df[['A','B']].melt()['value'].drop_duplicates().tolist()
print (L)
['x', 'y', 'k', 'l']
```

Comment: Thank you but the output gives the unique values in each column. Both columns have the save values and I do not want them to repeat in the list.
The output is:
['x', 'y', 'x', 'k', 'l']

Comment: @maerynore - Added 3 solution with ordering of original data.